# How replace position++ code to make it Swift 3 compatible?

Tags: swift

I have following class, which has method `getNextToken` to iterate array items:

```
class Parser {
    let tokens: [Token]
    var position = 0

    init(tokens: [Token]) {
        self.tokens = tokens
    }

    func getNextToken() -> Token? {
        guard position < tokens.count else {
            return nil
        }
    return tokens[position++]
    }
}
```

but i have a warning message from compiler that ++ will be deprecated in Swift 3

How should i rewrite my code to let method return array item at current position and increment position after that?

Standard recommendations to add one more line `position +=1` doesn't fit here because i am exiting from the scope exactly when i am evaluating `tokens[position++]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defer` can be used to increment the `position` variable
*after* the return value has been computed:

```
func getNextToken() -> Token? {
    guard position < tokens.count else {
        return nil
    }
    defer {
        position += 1
    }
    return tokens[position]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to assign the `token` to a let constant before incrementing `position`:

```
func getNextToken() -> Token? {
    guard position < tokens.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let token = tokens[position]
    position += 1
    return token
}
```

Another way is to save off the `current` value of `position`:

```
func getNextToken() -> Token? {
    guard position < tokens.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let current = position
    position += 1
    return tokens[current]
}
```

Or you could undo the increment:

```
func getNextToken() -> Token? {
    guard position < tokens.count else {
        return nil
    }
    position += 1
    return tokens[position - 1]
}
```